# ThreeJS, adding Subdivision Modifier to Objectloader-based scene

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm attempting to user the Subdivision Modifier on an objectloader-loaded scene.  I am getting the following javascript error when attempting this:

"BufferSubdivisionModifier.js:514 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined"

My code is the following to load the object with the subdivision modifier.

```
            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            loader.load("../js/brain2.json", function(object) {
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x888888, specular: 0x222222, shininess: 20} );

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            var modifier = new THREE.BufferSubdivisionModifier( 1 );
                            child.material = material;
                            child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                            modifier.modify( child.geometry );
                            child.material.overdraw = 1
                        };  
                    });
                    object.scale.set(15, 15, 15);
                    object.position.x = 1;
                    object.position.y = 1;
                    object.position.z = 1;
                    object.rotation.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                    scene.add( object );
            });
```

If I had to guess, it's that the subdivision modifier dislikes the 'child.geometry' object?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to load geometries for the chilren.

```
            var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            loader.load("../js/brain2.json", function(object) {
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x888888, specular: 0x222222, shininess: 20} );

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            child.material = material;
                             var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );
                             geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                             geometry.mergeVertices();
                             geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                             child.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );
                            var modifier = new THREE.BufferSubdivisionModifier(1);
                            modifier.modify(geometry);
                            child.material.overdraw = 1
                        };  
                    });
                    object.scale.set(15, 15, 15);
                    object.position.x = 1;
                    object.position.y = 1;
                    object.position.z = 1;
                    object.rotation.set( 5, 1, 1 );
                    scene.add( object );
            });
```